# Need to completely remove a device driver in windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, usb, driver, inf

I have an old USB device that is not recognized by windows 7, so I grabbed the device driver for the chip that handles the USB communications. After I modified it I used it to install for the device. Stupid I know, but now I need to get rid of it.

Below is the code from the inf setup file. This does not have the VID and PID that I changed. I need to reverse all the changes it made.

```
; Installation INF for the Cypress Generic USB Driver for Windows Vista
; Processor support for OS unknown platforms.
;
; (c) Copyright 2010 Cypress Semiconductor Corporation
;

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=USB
ClassGUID={36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}
provider=%CYUSB_Provider%
CatalogFile=CYUSB.cat
DriverVer=10/12/2010,3.4.4.000

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%CYUSB_Install%,,,

[SourceDisksFiles]
CYUSB.sys = 1

[DestinationDirs]
CYUSB.Files.Ext = 10,System32\Drivers

[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect = *

[Manufacturer]
%CYUSB_Provider%=Device,NT,NTx86,NTamd64

;for all platforms
[Device]
;%VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX


;for windows 2000 non intel platforms
[Device.NT]
; Cypress FX2LP default ID
%VID_04B4&PID_8613.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_8613

; Cypress FX1 default ID
%VID_04B4&PID_6473.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_6473

; Cypress Streamer Device.  CyStream firmware examples use this VID/PID
%VID_04B4&PID_1003.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_1003

; Cypress FX2LP Example Device.  DVK firmware examples use this VID/PID
%VID_04B4&PID_1004.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_1004


;for x86 platforms
[Device.NTx86]
; Cypress FX2LP default ID
%VID_04B4&PID_8613.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_8613

; Cypress FX1 default ID
%VID_04B4&PID_6473.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_6473


; Cypress Streamer Device.  CyStream firmware examples use this VID/PID
%VID_04B4&PID_1003.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_1003

; Cypress FX2LP Example Device.  DVK firmware examples use this VID/PID
%VID_04B4&PID_1004.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_1004


;for x64 platforms
[Device.NTamd64]
; Cypress FX2LP default ID
%VID_04B4&PID_8613.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_8613

; Cypress FX1 default ID
%VID_04B4&PID_6473.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_6473

; Cypress Streamer Device.  CyStream firmware examples use this VID/PID
%VID_04B4&PID_1003.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_1003

; Cypress FX2LP Example Device.  DVK firmware examples use this VID/PID
%VID_04B4&PID_1004.DeviceDesc%=CyUsb, USB\VID_04B4&PID_1004

[CYUSB]
CopyFiles=CYUSB.Files.Ext
AddReg=CyUsb.AddReg

[CYUSB.HW]
AddReg=CYUSB.AddReg.Guid

[CYUSB.Services]
Addservice = CYUSB,2,CYUSB.AddService

[CYUSB.NT]
CopyFiles=CYUSB.Files.Ext
AddReg=CyUsb.AddReg

[CYUSB.NT.HW]
AddReg=CYUSB.AddReg.Guid

[CYUSB.NT.Services]
Addservice = CYUSB,2,CYUSB.AddService


[CYUSB.NTx86]
CopyFiles=CYUSB.Files.Ext
AddReg=CyUsb.AddReg

[CYUSB.NTx86.HW]
AddReg=CYUSB.AddReg.Guid

[CYUSB.NTx86.Services]
Addservice = CYUSB,2,CYUSB.AddService

[CYUSB.NTamd64]
CopyFiles=CYUSB.Files.Ext
AddReg=CyUsb.AddReg

[CYUSB.NTamd64.HW]
AddReg=CYUSB.AddReg.Guid

[CYUSB.NTamd64.Services]
Addservice = CYUSB,2,CYUSB.AddService


[CYUSB.AddReg]
; Deprecating - do not use in new apps to identify a CYUSB driver
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,CYUSB.sys
; You may optionally include a check for DriverBase in your application to check for a CYUSB driver
HKR,,DriverBase,,CYUSB.sys
HKR,"Parameters","MaximumTransferSize",0x10001,4096
HKR,"Parameters","DebugLevel",0x10001,2
HKR,,FriendlyName,,%CYUSB_Description%

[CYUSB.AddService]
DisplayName    = %CYUSB_Description%
ServiceType    = 1                  ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 3                  ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 1                  ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary  = %10%\System32\Drivers\CYUSB.sys
AddReg         = CYUSB.AddReg
LoadOrderGroup = Base

[CYUSB.Files.Ext]
CYUSB.sys

[CYUSB.AddReg.Guid]
HKR,,DriverGUID,,%CYUSB.GUID%

[Strings]
CYUSB_Provider    = "Cypress"
CYUSB_Company     = "Cypress Semiconductor Corporation"
CYUSB_Description = "Cypress Generic USB Driver"
CYUSB_DisplayName = "Cypress USB Generic"
CYUSB_Install     = "Cypress CYUSB Driver Installation Disk"
VID_04B4&PID_8613.DeviceDesc="Cypress EZ-USB FX2LP No EEPROM"
VID_04B4&PID_6473.DeviceDesc="Cypress EZ-USB FX1 - No EEPROM"
VID_04B4&PID_1004.DeviceDesc="Cypress EZ-USB Example Device"
VID_04B4&PID_1003.DeviceDesc="Cypress EZ-USB Streamer Device"
VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX.DeviceDesc="Cypress USB Generic Driver (3.4.4.000)"
CYUSB.GUID="{AE18AA60-7F6A-11d4-97DD-00010229B959}"
CYUSB_Unused      = "."
```

Answer (score 45):

Another option (the Microsoft way, without doing random unknown deletings in the registry) is to start CMD as "run as admin" and then list all installed drivers in the Windows 7 driver store via:

> pnputil -e

if this caused a longer list you can pipe that into a file via:

> pnputil -e > C:\driverexport.txt

If you have found now the driver you need to remove use the following comand:

> pnputil.exe -d OemNUMBER.inf

replace NUMBER with your number from your example. You might try to use -F to force the uninstallation. Once a reboot is done the driver should be gone.

This might be also usefull to delete old drivers and get some HD space back.

[Source](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/solutions/windows/113-shrink-windows-7-for-ssd-usage.html)

Comment: Pnputil is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550428(v=vs.85).aspx   That page says  it comes with Windows, starting with Vista.

Comment: Sure it coms with Windows, otherwise I would mentioned a download here. However the content above was copy and pasted from the source URL which I mentioned at the bottom for completeness.

Comment: If it's a printer driver, this may not work. But you can go to **Print server properties** and remove the driver there.

Comment: An easier (and arguably less error-prone) method to find the oem.inf file name would be to go into **Device Manager**, right-click the device, go to **Properties**, then **Details** tab, and select INF Name from the dropdown list. Although at that point you might as well use the process as described by Preston below.

Comment: It might be not enough. I have had the Veracrypt application installed. Once I wanted to remove it and could not make it completely remove. The `veracrypt.sys` file does not list from `pnputil` command because has no inf file. But still shows in Device Manager in the list of disk drive driver files. Only sys file rename does remove it from the list.

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed a driver for a device and you want to remove it (and the driver store) just plug in your device. Open Device Manager, right click the device and select Uninstall. There will be a box that says "Remove driver software" - check this box and Uninstall the driver. This should remove it from the driver store and uninstall the device from the registry.

If all drivers for the device has been removed you should be able to plug it in and see that no driver loads for the device. If it does there could be multiple versions in your driver store and you go through the same steps until Windows doesn't recognize the device.

Note that the SYS file will remain in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers directory per policy, but if all devices and installations are removed that use it you can safely delete this driver as well.

Comment: The device has to be disabled (or not plugged in) for the "Remove driver software" checkbox to appear.

Comment: @Origin In my expierence with winusb.sys and usbser.sys drivers, that is not true.

Comment: I suspect that when you remove the final device instance that uses a particular driver, then the "remove driver software" checkbox appears. I have two devices that use the same driver. Only after uninstalling the second device was I presented with that checkbox. Does anyone else know?

Comment: @mitch, that's correct - it won't present that checkbox to let you remove the driver unless it's the last device using it is being removed.

Answer (score 1):

While the steps mentioned in answers above may be correct, this is a significantly easier method to do it:

Go to **Device Manager** or alternatively run the command

> devmgmt.msc

Right-click the device you need to uninstall and go to **Properties**. Select the **Details** tab and then select **INF Name** from the drop-down list

Once you have the INF Name type in this command in a command window opened with Admin privileges

> pnputil.exe -d *INFName.inf*

if you face issues try forced deletion

> pnputil.exe -f -d *INFName.inf*

Comment: Point to note here, the infs that can removed like this are third party infs with the name in form of oemX.inf where X is an integer, any other inf will fail